# Eloquent | Setting column value on insert

Tags: laravel, symfony, eloquent

So currently, I have a table which is for business locations in order to seperate the locations from the actual businesses table.

In this table, I want to store the longitude and latitude and obviously I can't get the user to input that without requiring them to do manual work which I really want to avoid.

So I wrote a class in order to get the longitude and latitude ready for entry to the database.

I've read online about doing `setLongitudeAttribute()` function within the model but I'm basing it off of the whole address which they are entering so I need to capture the whole of the request and then input it in myself.

I understand I can do this in the controller and do a custom insert but I didn't know if it was possible to keep it all contained within the model.

So essentially to break it down.

- User inputs the full address including all address lines and postal/zip code.
- Eloquent model captures this data.
- Converts the address to long and lat
- Model then handles the request in order to set the longitude and latitude based on the address.

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Models;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use App\Http\Calls\LongitudeLatitude;

  class BusinessLocation extends Model
  {
      /**
       * @var array
       */
      protected $fillable = [
          'business_id',
          'address_line_1',
          'address_line_2',
          'address_line_3',
          'address_line_4',
          'postcode',
          'longitude',
          'latitude'
      ];
      /**
       * @var string
       */
      protected $address;

  protected function setAddressLine1Attribute($value)
  {
      $this->address .= $value . '+';
      $this->attributes['address_line_1'] = $value;
  }

  protected function setAddressLine2Attribute($value)
  {
      $this->address .= $value . '+';
      $this->attributes['address_line_2'] = $value;
  }

  protected function setAddressLine3Attribute($value)
  {
      $this->address .= $value . '+';
      $this->attributes['address_line_3'] = $value;
  }

  protected function setAddress4Attribute($value)
  {
      $this->address .= $value . '+';
      $this->attributes['address_line_4'] = $value;
  }

  protected function setPostcodeAttribute($value)
  {
      $this->address .= $value;
      $this->attributes['postcode'] = $value;
      $this->setCoordinates();
  }

  protected function setCoordinates()
  {
      $long_lat = new LongitudeLatitude();
      $coords = $long_lat->get($this->address);

      $this->attributes['longitude'] = $coords['longitude'];
      $this->attributes['latitude'] = $coords['latitude'];
  }
  ```

Comment: you are about there, you can have whatever metod you need like `setCoordinate($address)` and do the computation (or can be a google map api request) for retrieving the coordinate of given address. i'm really against `setLongitudeAttribute()` as it actually magic method in Eloquent for 'preprocessing' single class properties. all you need is to think the model as a class.

Comment: So in that case, with the variable `$address` how would I then capture the data that is entered into the eloquent model?

Comment: As it's sent in completely seperate like `address_line_1` `address_line_2` `address_line_3` `address_line_4` etc

Comment: you can use `setAddressAtribute($address)`. and why it have to be `address_line1` and `address_line2` can explain the rationale of such approach? also, put your model on the question.. and what you have tried..

Comment: So for each line of the address I'll have to create a `setAddress1Attribute`  `setAddress2Attribute` ?

Comment: Having the addresses in separate columns within the database allow me to easily display them in the format that I want, on separate lines etc, also allows the user to easily update a single line in the address when they want to rather than editing the whole of the address.

Comment: hmm, if that is the case, i'd go with `setCoordinate($address)` instead of relying on magic function `setFooBarattribute` and call the `setCoordinate` before saving. since having `setAddress<number>Attribute` would give more harm than good done.

Comment: If that's the case and I aren't passing anything in through the `latitude` so I wont be able to capture the input, so on entry how would I then call the `setCoordinate($address)` ?

Comment: I've updated the question and this does exactly what I need. However, it doesn't exactly look pretty, hopefully this will get you an idea of what I need to do.

Comment: hi @tallent123, its roughly like that although if its me, i'd concatenate the address on `setCoordinates()` instead of on each `setFooBarAttribute` as it would be called on every `$model->address<number>` being set. regarding where this will be called, sadly, you will need to call this on the controller or model save event.

Comment: ps. you could go for full blown client side though, example: https://bitbucket.org/BagusTesa/ashadi-delivery-system-ads. that project uses client side api to get the longitude/latitude value and pass it to laravel as double without doing heavy task on saving the model.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and as you correctly mention, it doesn't look a good practice to write this logic in the model, but in the controller.

If I were you, I would leave the model logic to the model, and the rest to the controller and the other objects required to "transform" the input. This could even be done from the client with some javascript library if you will, sending just the lat and long to the server (your choice).

If you still want to create a method / setter in the model, I would recommend you to get some inspiration in any consolidated library, and the more official, the best, as for example: Laravel Cashier (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/billing), which provides extra behaviours to the model, in a separate logic unit.

If you want to follow Laravel Cashier approach, it uses a trait to apply the behaviour:
https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/7.0/src/Billable.php

It uses the official stripe package (it could be, in your case, the class you wrote, or any other such as Google Maps SDK) as well as other helper and data objects, which would make your model lighter in memory and make another objects responsible of the additional logic (easier to test and maintain), while it would also embed the behaviours in your model.

About your code...

You can not guarantee that the setters are executed in the order you want (or you shouldn't trust it will always do), so, in case you want to continue with the code you already have, I would suggest to move `$this->setCoordinates();` to somewhere else, for example an event observer such as `creating`, `updating` and `saving`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

And also evaluate the address every time you call it, as follows:

```
public function setCoordinates()
{
    $address = $this->attributes['address_line_1'] . '+' .
        $this->attributes['address_line_2'] . '+' .
        $this->attributes['address_line_3'] . '+' .
        $this->attributes['address_line_4'] . '+' .
        $this->attributes['postcode'];

    $long_lat = new LongitudeLatitude();
    $coords = $long_lat->get($address);

    $this->attributes['longitude'] = $coords['longitude'];
    $this->attributes['latitude'] = $coords['latitude'];
}
```

Notice that the method is public, so you can call it from the event observer.

There are other business logic factors to consider:
 - Do you want to give the possibility to fill manually the coordinates? if not, you should remove them from the `$fillable` array.
 - Do you really need to evaluate the coordinates every time you update any of the address fields? Then you may want to have a status property to verify if the coordinates are pristine (in address fields setters set pristine as false, in coordinates getters check if the value is null or if it's not pristine, and if so, set the coordinates again).